# Google Sign Up without mobile phone with Puppeteer Stealth

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm using the following code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
const generator = require('generate-password');
const username = 'AlexBenson' + Date.now();
const ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.91 Mobile Safari/537.36';
const signUpUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/signup/v2/createaccount?flowEntry=SignUp'
const password = generator.generate({
    length: 15,
    numbers: true
});

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())
puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--enable-webgl',
        '--window-size=800,800'
    ]
}).then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setUserAgent(ua);
    await page.goto(signUpUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await page.type('input[name="firstName"]', 'Alex', { delay: 100 });
    await page.type('input[name="lastName"]', 'Benson', { delay: 100 });
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter')

    await page.waitForTimeout(1500)

    // Fill in the date of birth, gender, and submit
    await page.type('#day', '10', { delay: 100 });
    await page.select('#month', '1');
    await page.type('#year', '1980', { delay: 100 });
    await page.select('#gender', '3'); // Assuming "Rather not to say" has the value of '3'
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter');

    await page.waitForTimeout(1500);

    // Fill in the email
    await page.type('input[name="Username"]', username);
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter');

    await page.waitForTimeout(1500);

    // Fill in the password fields
    await page.type('input[name="Passwd"]', password, { delay: 100 });
    await page.type('input[name="PasswdAgain"]', password, { delay: 100 });
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter');

    await page.waitForTimeout(10000);
    await browser.close()
})
```

To go over the Sign Up process howaver at the last step Google detects that I'm a robot and shows extra step to validate signup via mobile number. Is there a way to skip this, I'm already using Stealth?

Thanks